# Prevent pipe from going into sub-shell of script

Tags: php, shell, pipe

I'm piping lines into a PHP script (see contrived example below). Alas the pipe unintentionally flows into the shell command in the script, thus nano doesn't run because it chokes on STDIN.

I want the shell command to run completely unrelated to the STDIN piped to the main script. So the PHP script should in a way "eat" the STDIN, so it doesn't reach the sub-shell. How do I fix this?

Note that `exec()`, `system()` and `passthru()` all give the same result.

```
$ echo -e "World\nEverybody" | php script.php
Hello World
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
Hello Everybody
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

script.php:

```
<?php

foreach(file("php://stdin") as $name) {
  echo "Hello $name";
  passthru("nano");
}

?>
```

Environment:

- PHP 7.1.14 / PHP 5.6.30
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57
- GNU nano version 2.0.6

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I run the php script and the command line it works as expected. Can it be related to the version/type of shell or php? I use php 5.6 and Bash 4.4

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: See updated question. Basically, using STDIN in a script, and being able to launch a shell without the shell getting the STDIN.

Comment: @AlexPerrin: See updated question. PHP 7.1.14 / PHP 5.6.30 & GNU bash, version 3.2.57

Comment: I dont think this is how it will work. In the PHP script, stdin is a meta file. you can read and perform operations on it. Running a detached shell requires something else completely unrelated to this stdin. I think you should try changing the approach to this. and peraphs make it more clear what you want to achieve. In any case, try with "bash -c 'nano'"

Comment: Try e.g. `passthru("nano </dev/tty");` Does that do what you want?

Comment: @sneep: It does indeed work! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Though in that case, I think your question is slightly off. When I read "the pipe flows into `nano`", I imagined that `nano` would eat "Everybody". But in reality, PHP got both, and `nano` got nothing. (If `nano` had gotten something (as in echo foo | nano), nano would have auto-saved something in `nano.save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The pipe isn't really flowing into the sub-shells. In fact, nothing is flowing in.</del> In order to connect `nano`'s STDIN to the terminal, you pipe the controlling terminal (always `/dev/tty`) into nano, like this:

```
passthru("nano </dev/tty");
```

---

Here's an answer to your follow-up question. (Very good question IMO. My previous answer was slightly wrong in fact. STDIN does flow into the child processes.)

> If the script consists of just passthru("nano") and you don't pipe anything into PHP, then nano works without </dev/tty. Why is this?

### Linux behavior

In fact, child processes do inherit STDIN from their parent processes, but because of buffering, this isn't entirely clear sometimes. And since they inherit the same STDIN, when EOF is reached, they do whatever they do when EOF is reached (to see what `nano` does in this case, see below).

Let's take PHP out of the equation and see what we get when we turn buffering on or off. Here's some C code that will read from STDIN, system(), and read from STDIN again:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
    char buffer[32];
    gets(buffer);
    printf("Hello %s\n", buffer);
    system("bash -c 'read FOO; echo This is bash, got $FOO'");
    gets(buffer);
    printf("Hello2 %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Compile (ignore the warnings about `gets`) and run:

```
$ cc -o script script.c
$ echo -e "Foo\nBar\nCar" | ./script
Hello Foo
This is bash, got
Hello2 Bar
```

`bash` didn't get anything. The `gets` after `system` magically got this input. Now uncomment the first line:

```
-    // setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
+    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
```

And we get:

```
$ cc -o script script.c
$ echo -e "Foo\nBar\nCar" | ./script
Hello Foo
This is bash, got Bar
Hello2 Car
```

This time `bash` got the second input. "Too long; didn't read": We do in fact have the same STDIN.

### `nano` internals

First of all, you will find that `nano`'s behavior is the same even if you take PHP out of the equation:

```
$ echo foo | nano
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

`nano` could in theory very well detect if we've got a terminal, and if we don't, attempt to open `/dev/tty` (it's just a regular `open` call). In fact, `nano` does this if you execute `nano` like this:

```
echo foo | nano -
```

The `scoop_stdin` function in `src/nano.c` takes care of this in version 2.9.4: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/nano.c?h=v2.9.4#n1122

And the `finish_stdin_pager` function in version 2.7.4: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/nano.c?h=v2.7.4#n1116)

So what happens when `nano` gets EOF? EOF in key input is handled like this:
Version 2.7.4: `get_key_buffer()` calls `handle_hupterm(0)` directly.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/winio.c?h=v2.7.4#n207

Version 2.9.4: `die(_("Too many errors from stdin"));`

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/winio.c?h=v2.9.4#n207

(The reason I'm linking both is because the message changed at some point.)

I hope that sort of makes things clearer.

Comment: If the script consists of just `passthru("nano")` and you don't pipe anything into PHP, then nano works without `</dev/tty`. Why is this?

Comment: Edited my post to address your follow-up question

Comment: Very good explanation! However, what do you propose that `echo foo | nano -` should achieve, because here it produces `Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM. Buffer written to -.save`. Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50191/piped-input-to-nano, perhaps? Mine is GNU nano version 2.0.6.

Comment: Oh, looks like your version of `nano` doesn't have this feature. In more recent versions, you'd get an editor with "foo" on the first line.